# How customise log file on Yii Framework?

Tags: php, logging, yii, logfiles

I am trying to handle errors on my website. I logs each error in my log files, but I would like to know how to customize the message that is recorded in the log file.

For now, I get this message:

> 2013/09/30 10:08:59 [error] [exception.CException] exception
>   'CException' with message 'Error test' in
>   myDomain.com\protected\controllers\SiteController.php:234

Can you help me?

Comment: you can use Yii::log($message, $level, $category);

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have a other question. How do you make for removing the "stack trace" ?

Comment: I think you can modify this line `defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);` in your `index.php` file

Answer (score 2):

For manual customization log messages you need to create your own LogRoute class. In your situation you need inherit class from CFileLogRoute and override method formatLogMessage (such in example):

> ```
> class MyFileLogRoute extends CFileLogRoute{
>     protected function formatLogMessage($message,$level,$category,$time)
>     {
>         //enter code here your custom message format
>         return @date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time)." [$level] [$category] $message\n";
>     }
> }
> ```

Than configure your configuration file:

> ```
>        'log' => array(
>            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
>            'routes' => array(
>                array(
>                    'class' => 'MyFileLogRoute',
>                    'levels' => 'error, warning, info',
>                    'categories' => 'application.*',
>                    'logPath' => dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../../logs/',
>                ),
>                ...
> ```

And yes, @ragingprodigy is right: you can set `define('YII_DEBUG', 0)` or `define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 0)` in index.php to remove stack trace from log messages